# CSS - Unwanted Break

Tags: html, css, break

I wan't to show a list of videos on my website, as many in a row as possible.
On the left side I want a navigation area. Next to the navigation I want to place the first videos.

Unfortunately the videos will be placed below the navigation. I already tried display: inline-block; and so on but there has been no solution yet.

What did I do wrong?
[image]

```
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="navigation_area"></div><!-- div end video area -->

    <div id="video_area">
        <div class="video_container">
            <div class="video_thumb"></div>
            <div class="video_info_container">
                <div class="video_name">Video Name 1</div>
                <div class="rating_container">
                    <div class="rating"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- video_container -->

        <div class ="video_container">
            <div class="video_thumb"></div>
            <div class="video_info_container">
                <div class="video_name">Video Name 2</div>
                <div class="rating_container">
                    <div class="rating"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- video_container -->

    </div> <!--div end video area-->
</div><!--div end content_wrapper-->
```

css:

```
navigation_area{
    height:500px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    margin:2px;
}

#video_area{
    float: left;
}

.video_container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float: left` from `#video_area` and `.video_container` and add `float: left` to `#navigation_area` instead. Change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block`

```
#navigation_area{
    ...
    float: left;
}

.video_container{
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Complete [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9AJZh/2/)

If you want to keep the `video_area` to the right of `navigation_area`, no matter what, you can set a `min-width` for the `content_area`

```
#content_wrapper {
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9AJZh/3/)

Comment: best approach so far, thanks. Unfortunately when I reduce the browser width the video_area will break again.

Comment: I just added a lot of videos. They will break when they reached the bottom of #navigation_area.

Comment: I edited my css: #video_area{
margin-left: 120px;
}. Please let me know if you'd choose a different way.

Comment: @Goot I can't test IE here, sorry. This is a Linux only system.

Answer (score 1):

Try floating your navigation_area to the left as well.

Don't forget the # before the style id